# Python requests.post(url) works in shell but doesn't work in PyCharm

Tags: python-2.7, windows-10, python-requests, pycharm

So when I do this simple thing with requests in SHELL everything works fine and displays the page content and ok status:

```
>>> payload = (('key1', 'value1'), ('key1', 'value2'))
>>> r = requests.post('myurl....', data=payload)
>>> print r.status_code
>>> print r.content
```

When I do it in Pycharm I still get status code 200 meaning it worked, but when I try to display the content, instead of full webpage I get empty result. The same goes for r.text... even debugger shows it empty. Using tuple shows the same emptiness:

```
>>> print ( (r.content), )
{ 
('',) 
}
```

Does anyone have any idea? I know about environmental variables being the most obvious problem, especially on windows, but I went that route, doublechecked everything, all seems ok.

Still, I uninstalled PyCharm and Python, restarted, reinstalled them, PIPed all the latest versions of packages... and same result.

I even tried LiClipse with the same results. I'm very thankful for any experienced person's idea about this.